# Showing Error "can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

This is my code I want to import all the wav file stored in my desktop. But every time it showing some error if I'm changing the backslash. EOL error is showing.

```
no_of_recordings=[]
for label in labels:
    waves = [f for f in os.listdir('Desktop/yes' + '/'+ labels) if f.endswith('.wav')]
    no_of_recordings.append(len(waves))
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: Did you mean `os.listdir('Desktop/yes' + '/'+ label)`?

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo, use the iterating current object instead of the list:

```
os.listdir('Desktop/yes' + '/'+ label)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing typo. But it showing an issue about directory.                                                       
           NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'Desktop/yes/004ae714_nohash_0.wav'                                                        where '004ae714_nohash_0.wav' is one of the wav file stored in yes folder.